# What are all the responses from Twilio Fetch a Verification by SID?

Tags: rest, twilio

### Documentation:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification#fetch-a-verification

### Backgroud

After reading the documentation the functionality is simple. I am checking the status of my code so I know when to prompt my user to enter it or try the process again if errors occur.

### Issues

When I test my phone number I receive "pending" every time yet the code has already been sent. I cannot find a full list of responses from the Twilio API. This is the only response.

I am assuming that it returns pending because the verification of the device is pending. So what do I check to see if the message was sent to the user?

I cannot find the description of the response keys so it makes it difficult to understand which key to check.

```
{
  "sid": "VEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "service_sid": "VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "account_sid": "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "to": "+15017122661",
  "channel": "sms",
  "status": "pending",
  "valid": false,
  "date_created": "2015-07-30T20:00:00Z",
  "date_updated": "2015-07-30T20:00:00Z",
  "lookup": {
    "carrier": {
      "error_code": null,
      "name": "Carrier Name",
      "mobile_country_code": "310",
      "mobile_network_code": "150",
      "type": "mobile"
    }
  },
  "amount": null,
  "payee": null,
  "send_code_attempts": [
    {
      "time": "2015-07-30T20:00:00Z",
      "channel": "SMS",
      "channel_id": null
    }
  ],
  "url": "https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Verifications/VEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [properties are described in the documentation under "Verification Response Properties"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification#verification-response-properties). The entry for "status" reads:

> The status of the verification. One of: `pending`, `approved`, or `canceled`

Once you have created a verification it will be in "pending" status until it [is successfully checked](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification-check).

Checking whether a message has been sent is as simple as a status, when you consider that Twilio Verify can send verifications by SMS, WhatsApp, Voice call or email. You should assume that once you have successfully created a Verification that Twilio will enact the delivery of the code over the chosen channel.

This [blog post might give you some good ideas for how to control the experience for you users and create a UI that helps them receive the verification codes successfully](https://www.twilio.com/blog/best-practices-phone-number-validation-user-enrollment).